# Use blob variables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, variables, select

I have a mysql query like this:

```
set @category = '37,44,46';
SELECT * from products where category_id IN (@category);
```

But it returns Null.
If I try to SELECT * from products where category_id IN (37,44,46) — it works.

@category is a BLOB variable (it's generating by another query).

I tried to write SELECT * from products where category_id IN (SELECT @category), but it doesn't work too :(

Comment: If you take a closer look to what you wrote, you'll see that what you DO is `where category_id IN('37,44,46')` which doesn't work and then you're referencing `where category_id IN(37,44,46)` which *does* work.  Note the difference and you'll understand why Raymond N's answer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something more like this

```
SET @category = '37,44,46';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id IN (',@category,')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

check out the sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a1eb0/1